# SELECT MAX query issue interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the highest value in the last 1 day, but the query is not working.
(date / time columns formatted by date).
The data I want to query is in multiple headers.

```
SELECT sign, date, price, MAX(price) as maxp FROM table WHERE datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

my full query;

```
$que = $conn->mysql_query("SELECT sign, date, MAX(price) as maxp FROM table WHERE date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) group by sign, date"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($que); { 

?>

<?php
foreach ($que as $row) {
$newQuery = "UPDATE tableb SET `daymax`='".$row["maxp"]."' where `sign`='".$row["sign"]."' ";
mysqli_multi_query($conn, $newQuery)

?>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Chakri "query empty." but not is empty.

Comment: And you cannot mix-and-match APIs. Throw out the deprecated one (mysql_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want sign,date wise max price you need to group by on sign,date. Try this.

```
SELECT sign, date, MAX(price) as maxp 
FROM table WHERE datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
group by sign,date
```

Comment: "query empty" . I have added my full query. There may be a problem in the entire query

Comment: Please share full query with table structures.

Comment: PLEASE CHECK IF YOU HAVE DATA IN THIS DATE RANGE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one query:

```
update tableb b join
       (selecct sign, MAX(price) as maxp 
        from table t
        where datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        group by sign
       ) tt
       on b.sign = tt.sign
    set b.daymax = tt.maxp;
```

Let the database do the work!  There is no reason to do looping in the application when you can do it in the database.

Note that `now()` has a time component.  You are working with dates, so you might really want `curdate()` instead.